# How to clear the JFrame or JPanel?

Tags: jframe

I am planing to develop a quiz program in a JFrame , so after the first question i want to display the second question , so I should clear the first question to display the second question, in C I know it is clrscr(); but in Java I don' know any one can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call

```
getContentPane().removeAll();
```

removeAll() has not been overridden as add() or remove() to forward to the contentPane as necessary.

Comment: Do you get an error? can you please give me more information?

Comment: yes, thank you it is working, actually i don't know java, but i am trying to lern,  can you explain what is getContentPane() , why because when i am trying to insert a image on jframe thre it is needed

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this
getContentPane().removeAll();